# Max value of int in ChucK

Tags: chuck

What is the maximum value of an int in ChucK?  Is there a symbolic constant for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New in the latest version!

```
<<<Math.INT_MAX>>>;
```

For reference though, it uses the "`long`" keyword in C++ to represent integers.
So on 32-bit computers the max should be `0x7FFFFFFF`, or `2147483647`.
On 64-bit computers it will be `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, or `9223372036854775807`.

Answer from Kassen and Stephen Sinclair on the [chuck-users mailing list](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/mailman/listinfo/chuck-users).

Answer (score 1):

[The ChucK API reference](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/program/stdlib.html) uses the C `int` type, so the maximum value would depend on your local machine (2^31-1, around two billion on standard 32-bit x86). I don't see any references to retrieving limits, but if ChucK is extensible using C you could add a function that returns `MAXINT`.